# Symfony2 - 2 entities in 1 form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Here's the case, a forum system with 3 main Entities:

- Forum
- Thread
- Post

When you are creating a new Thread, the form should provide you basically with 2 fields:

- Thread Name
- Text area for first Post

I know I can put an extra field, then use the request object to get the information from it but it looks like the worst solution you can think of.

I believe you can think of a better solution.

So here are the questions:
* How would you get the form to display both sub-forms (for Post and Thread entities) - (Using PostType and ThreadType classes if possible)
* Will this make it validate those forms on submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try looking into symfony2 documentation about embedded forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms

Comment: I found this to be a great source but I could not manage relations is an acceptable way so I made thread table to have the first post. They are logically one thing (The thread and it's fist post, which can be taken as a "description" field too) so i think it's ok to have the first post of a thread in the Threads table) This fixed the problem for me. And embeded forms would be great for one-to-one and one-to-many relations really. Thanks for your answer once again.